# readTimeout on httpURLConnection.getOutputStream()?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, outputstream, urlconnection, socket-timeout-exception

I have an `HttpURLConnection` with a `readTimeout` set to 500 milliseconds for testing. Based from my understanding, `readTimeout` is the maximum allowable time to wait for a response. However, when I run my application, an Exception is thrown at `getOutputStream`. The `Exception` is apparently due to the `readTimeout`.

Why did `readTimeout` occur at `getOutputStream`? I thought `getOutputStream` is only for sending data and therefore, it should not wait for any response. And since it doesn't have to wait for any response, `readTimeout` cannot happen. Intially, I thought the `readTimeout` will occur at `getInputStream` because it is where the response is being received/ read. Can you explain how a `readTimeout` and `connectTimeout` works?

Also, when I put a timer before and after `getOutputStream`, the value of my timer after invoking `getOutputStream` is only 200+ milliseconds. My `readTimeout` is 500 milliseconds. Why did `getOutputStream` timed out earlier than the 500 milliseconds value of my `readTimeout`? Please note that my `connectTimeout` is set to 0 or infinite.

Comment: Does this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816824/httpurlconnection-post-conn-getoutputstream-throwing-exception

Comment: @Dave: Thanks! But there is no readTimeout set on the link you gave me. My question is how does readTimeout affects getOutputStream when I thought readTimeout is supposed for getInputStream.