# Create a plain HTTP PUT multipart request with a jpg attached

Tags: http, post, multipartform-data, put

I'm creating a HTTP PUT request manualy. I have the following format

```
POST http://server.com/id/55/push HTTP/1.0
Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x
Content-Length: 168

--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="small.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<file content>
--AaB03x--
```

My question is, how should I fill the "file content" area? If I open a jpeg with TexMate or with cat command line application and I paste the ASCII output, the request does not work.

## UPDATE

I'm working with a microprocessor and I can't use C or a high level language I need to manually do the raw request. Do I need to separate with spaces every binary byte read from the file?

In case of saving the jpg into a file in the server side, Do I have to convert the binary stream to ASCII?

I read the binary code of a JPG from my hard drive with a simple php conde:

```
$filename = "pic.jpg";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$fsize = filesize($filename);
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
//echo $contents;
for($i = 0; $i < $fsize; $i++)
{ 
  // get the current ASCII character representation of the current byte
   $asciiCharacter = $contents[$i];
   // get the base 10 value of the current characer
   $base10value = ord($asciiCharacter);
   // now convert that byte from base 10 to base 2 (i.e 01001010...)
   $base2representation = base_convert($base10value, 10, 2);
   // print the 0s and 1s
   echo($base2representation);
}
```

whit this code I get a stream of 1 and 0. I can send it including the string of 101010101... to where the tag "file content" of my manually http request is but in the server side I can't visualise the JPG... ¿should I convert it to ASCII again?

### SOLUTION

Okay the solution was very simple, I just dumped the ASCII code into the tag "file content" of the http request. Despite I'm using a micro controller I opened a socket with PHP and tested out. The solution was to read the ASCII from the file instead of paste directly the ASCII into the code.

Here a working example of the solution:

```
<?php

//We read the file from the hard drive
$filename = "pic.jpg";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$fsize = filesize($filename);
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);

$mesage = $contents;

//A trick to calculate the length of the HTTP body
$len = strlen('--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="small.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

'.$mesage.'
--AaB03x--');


//We create the HTTP request
$out = "POST /temp/test.php HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$out .= "Content-type: multipart/form-data boundary=AaB03x\r\n";
$out .= "Content-Length: $len\r\n\r\n";

$out .= "--AaB03x\r\n";
$out .= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"small.jpg\"\r\n";
$out .= "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n";
$out .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n";

$out .= "$mesage\r\n";
$out .= "--AaB03x--\r\n\r\n";

//Open the socket 
$fp = fsockopen("127.0.0.1", 8888, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    
    //we send the message thought the opened socket
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}

//Visualize the query sent
echo nl2br($out);
?>
```

In the real implementation I will simple read directly from the memory of the microcontroler just as I did in the php

Answer (score 0):

You are mistyping the last boundary, it should have been:

```
--AaB03x--
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an OutputStream of your outcoming connection and use this Stream to write ALL BYTES that you have read from the file.

If you used C#. You can check this: [Sending Files using HTTP POST in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738847/sending-files-using-http-post-in-c-sharp)

For Java:

- [Image writing over URLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883379/image-writing-over-urlconnection)
- [how to send data with file upload to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064479/how-to-send-data-with-file-upload-to-the-server)
- [HttpURLConnection POST, conn.getOutputStream() throwing Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816824/httpurlconnection-post-conn-getoutputstream-throwing-exception)